# No openstreetmap visible, why?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, openlayers, openstreetmap

I am trying to use openstreetmap instead of google maps but no map is visible. When I test almost the same code with a html site it works but not in my mvc2 application. WHY???

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<TDXWeb.ViewModel.MapViewModel>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="pathTo/OpenLayers.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.openstreetmap.org/openlayers/OpenStreetMap.js"></script>    

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function initializeMap()
        {
            var lat = 47.496792
            var lon = 7.571726
            var zoom = 13

            var map;
            /* Create Map */

            // Create a map with some default values that will be altered later
            map = new OpenLayers.Map (document.getElementById(
            "map_canvas"), {
                controls:[
                    new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(),
                    new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar(),
                    new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher(),
                    new OpenLayers.Control.Attribution()],
                maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-20037508.34,-20037508.34,20037508.34,20037508.34),
                maxResolution: 156543.0399,
                numZoomLevels: 19,
                units: 'm',
                projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),
                displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")
            } );            

            // Define the map layer
            // Here we use a predefined layer that will be kept up to date with URL changes
            layerMapnik = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM.Mapnik("Mapnik");
            map.addLayer(layerMapnik);
            layerCycleMap = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM.CycleMap("CycleMap");
            map.addLayer(layerCycleMap);
            layerMarkers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers("Markers");
            map.addLayer(layerMarkers);         

            var lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(lon, lat).transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), map.getProjectionObject());
            map.setCenter(lonLat, zoom);

            var size = new OpenLayers.Size(21, 25);
            var offset = new OpenLayers.Pixel(-(size.w/2), -size.h);
            var icon = new OpenLayers.Icon('http://www.openstreetmap.org/openlayers/img/marker.png',size,offset);
            layerMarkers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(lonLat,icon));

            $('#map_canvas').resizable();            
        }      
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            initializeMap();

        });    
    </script>
    <div class="formitemmap">
    <h3>Karta</h3>

    <div class="text">Här kan du se dina fordon. Välj vilka du vill ska visas på kartan.</div>

    <div id="map_canvas" style="min-width: 1050px; min-height: 1050px; float:left;"></div>

    <% using (Html.BeginForm("DisplayClientMap", "Map", FormMethod.Post))
    {%>
        <% if (Model != null && Model.Vehicles != null)
            {  %>                

                <%= Html.Grid(Model.Vehicles)
                        .Columns(column =>
                        {
                            column.For(v => v.UnitNumber).Named("Enhet");
                            column.For(v => Html.CheckBoxFor(v2 => v.Display)).Named("Visa");
                            column.For(v => Html.HiddenFor(v2 => v.UnitNumber)).Attributes(style => "display: none;").HeaderAttributes(style => "display: none;");
                        })
                                .Empty("Hittade inga enheter.")                                
                %>


                <% if (Model.VehiclesHasNoGeoData != null && Model.VehiclesHasNoGeoData.Count > 0)
                   { %>
                       <div class="text" style="display: block; font-size: x-small; font-weight:bold">&nbsp;GPS-positioner saknas för: </div>
                        <% foreach (int radioNumber in Model.VehiclesHasNoGeoData)
                            { %>
                                <div class="text" style="display: list-item; font-size: x-small; color:Red; font-weight:bold">&nbsp;<%: radioNumber%> </div> 
                        <% } %>
                <% } %>


                <% if (Model.VehiclesNotFound != null && Model.VehiclesNotFound.Count > 0)
                   { %>
                        <div class="text" style="display: block; font-size: x-small;"> Följande enheter hade ingen match i databasen: </div>
                        <% foreach (int radioNumber in Model.VehiclesNotFound)
                            { %>
                                <div class="text" style="display: list-item; font-size: x-small;"> <%: radioNumber%> </div> 
                        <% } %>
                <% } %>


                <% if (Model.Vehicles.Count() > 0)
                    { %>
                        <input type="submit" style="margin-top:20px;"  id="Submit_button" value="Visa enheter" />
                <% } %>
        <% } %>
    <% } %>
    </div>

</asp:Content>
```

Can anyone find the problem and help me with a solution?

Comment: Do you see any OpenLayer controls or is the map completely empty? Did you already try to debug your application in order to see if it tries to fetch tiles (images)?

Comment: It is completely empty. When I have a html-file with the map is visible with the same code

Comment: Then try to debug it. Is the `initializeMap()` function called?

Comment: Are there any refers blocked by your MS Server?

Comment: How do I see if there are any refers blocket?

Comment: It would be a good idea to avoid mixing ASP and JS code so much, it effectively makes it impossible to reproduce your setup or follow the logic. Perhaps you could try to simplify your example until you can squeeze it into a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: I found out why the map was not visible but I have not found a solution yet. 

"Cross-origin image load denied by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy." 

How do I enable Cross-origin image load?
I have been searching for answer but none of the one found had helped me. 

IIS 8 and asp.net mvc2.......

Answer (score 0):

I see you're pulling in a script from `http://www.openstreetmap.org/openlayers/OpenStreetMap.js` which is something you get in some older example snippets, but I think I'm right in saying this is no longer recommended.

It will work without that provided you tweak the way the layers are added. Instead of this:

```
        layerMapnik = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM.Mapnik("Mapnik");
        map.addLayer(layerMapnik);
        layerCycleMap = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM.CycleMap("CycleMap");
        map.addLayer(layerCycleMap);
```

Try just doing

```
        layerOSM = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();
        map.addLayer(layerOSM);
```

You mentioned you're seeing *"**Cross-origin image load denied by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy.**"* errors. I've noticed some tile servers cause this error, but not normally the 'standard' map tiles from OpenStreetMap. See [this example which adds several different tile sources](http://harrywood.co.uk/maps/examples/openlayers/many-layers.view.html). It adds a layer such as this one:

```
    watercolour = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("Stamen watercolour",                                                   
            ["http://tile.stamen.com/watercolor/${z}/${x}/${y}.png"],
            {attribution: "&copy; <a href='http://www.openstreetmap.org/'>OpenStreetMap</a> and contributors, under an <a href='http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright' title='ODbL'>open license</a>. Watercolour style by <a href='http://stamen.com'>Stamen Design</a>",
             "tileOptions": { "crossOriginKeyword": null }}));
    map.addLayer(watercolour);
```

...where `"tileOptions": { "crossOriginKeyword": null }` is some OpenLayers magic needed to make it work.

In general there's a lot of different reasons for OpenLayers to refuse to show anything. Projections are the usual headache. If you get it wrong when you initialise the map or when you call map.setCenter, then you'll see nothing. Best to [start simple](http://harrywood.co.uk/maps/examples/openlayers/simple.view.html) and build up. But the [LeafletJS](http://leafletjs.com) web map library is easier to get started with.